# Setting an array of "eventNotifications" on an envelope has no effect

Tags: docusignapi

The eSign REST api docs for the `POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes` endpoint states that you should be able to add "An array of eventNotification objects" by using the property `eventNotifications`.

It seems though, after a lot of hair pulling, that settings this property has no effect whatsoever. In fact, it seems you can set any property you want and the API will just happily accept it and say nothing.

I'm surprised this issue hasn't been raised previously, but I can't seem to find any other mention.

Could you  please let me know if this really is a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The `eventNotifications` array has no affect. I apologize for the time and effort this documentation bug caused you.

Please use the single `eventNotification` attribute.

I filed an internal bug report on this, DEVDOCS-2972, previously. I have now pinged the engineer to prioritize the bug to have the attribute removed from our documentation.